# jQuery - Change boolean value after 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this config on my page:

```
<script>
    var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
    window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
        continuous: false,
        disableTouch: false,
    });
</script>
```

I was wondering is it possible to make it so 10 seconds after the page has finished loading to change the value of `disableTouch` to `true`?

Comment: use a timeout inside window onload handler...

Comment: @A.Wolff Hey, are you able to make that happen with my code and then post it in full? jQuery isn't my strong suit. Thank you!

Comment: For basic task like that, no I won't... Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a slow day. I'll help :)

```
var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
  continuous: false,
  disableTouch: false,
});

function setDisableTouchToTrue(){
  window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
    continuous: false,
    disableTouch: true,
  });
}

window.onload = setTimeout(setDisableTouchToTrue, 10000);
```

Maybe you can even do:

```
function setDisableTouchToTrue(){
  window.mySwipe.disableTouch = true;
}
```

Not sure.

Comment: Very much appreciated! Thank you! That worked :) Sorry!

Comment: No probs. Don't be sorry :) Everyone has to learn somewhere.

Comment: @JackZelig +1 for the `slow day` (:

Answer (score 1):

Altho it's a possible duplicate, i will suggest this since you'r new. Use `setTimeout()` on document `ready()` as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { setTimeout(function() {
        var elem = document.getElementById('mySwipe');
        window.mySwipe = Swipe(elem, {
            continuous: false,
            disableTouch: true,
        });
    }, 10 * 1000);
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your answer. Sorry once again.